# CSS - Text with transparent color to see background image

Tags: css, cross-browser, transparent

I need to make a transparent text and you see what's below (an image)

The image moves and I need to look through the text to move the image.

Example:

[image]

Comment: I think this is impossible - you should use image (png or gif with transparency) for that...

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: I have made very many tests, and I've searched a lot online, but I think the only solution is to use transparent PNG's

Comment: I have done many tests, and the most I've managed to do is this: http://incut.es/desarrollo/__PRUEBAS/letras_recortadas_1/ The text is transparent, but the text box does not get to color. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

just use the opacity property

```
 opacity:0;
```

example in here : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Comment: Completely wrong. The requirement is for the TEXT to be transparent which whilst technically possible would render it invisible.

Comment: if use opacity:0 text disappears and is not seen

Comment: @Javichuteck my bad, i taught you wanted to mask the text that's why i suggested to put opacity to 0

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

Remember that text is an element in and of itself. If you make the text transparent then the background of the parent will show through.

In your case, you have a partially transparent white background. If you made the text transparent that bg color would show and the text would, effectively, disappear.

Answer (score 0):

simplest would be to use opacity : **fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/34Adc/

**CSS**

```
  color:rgba(252, 205, 77,
0.7 /* this is opacity */
);
```

Comment: the text is required to be FULLY transparent.

Comment: @Paulie_D : question says `I need to make a transparent text`...what does it mean then????

Comment: 100% see-through...not partially as you have indicated. Did you look at the image in the OP?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using css background-clip if the image is not dynamicaly resized and you know precisely the position of the text